# Flutter web, onTap in being called twice on safari

Tags: flutter, safari, flutter-web

On Safari for some of my onTap functions, my code is being executed twice. It doesn't always happen just from times to times.

for example:

```
goToSearchPage() {
    Navigator.pushNamed(
      context, '/searchPage',
      arguments: SearchPageArguments(
         matchcode: _controllerSearchInput.text.trim().toString()
      )
    );

    _controllerSearchInput.text = '';
}    

onTap: () {
      _controllerSearchInput.text = matchcode;
      goToSearchPage();
},
```

When onTap sometimes it loads 2 times `searchpage`, first time with a correct argument and second time with an empty argument.

An other example:

```
onTap: () {
  setState(() {
    _loading = true;
  });
  http.Client()
  .get("https://myApi")
  .then((response) =>response.body)
  .then(json.decode)
  .then((json) {
    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
    });

    Navigator.popAndPushNamed(
      context, '/paymentPage',
      arguments: PaymentPageArguments(
        ordersToPay: json
      )
    );
  });
}
```

In this case after my API is being called `paymentPage` is not showing because I think navigator is being pop twice instead of one time. My API is only being call one time though.

Those weird behaviors only happens in safari, I'm not sure how i could debug it.

Comment: Which widget did you use to perform your onTap ? Did you try using another widget with a similar gesture to see if it was working the same way ?

Comment: One thing I noticed about your functions is that they ignore all warnings and don't await their futures. That means the calling function thinks they are done, when in fact they are not. That might not be your current problem, but it will come back to haunt you sooner or later. Maybe fix that first, see if it fixes your current problem, if not, no harm done, did something good anyway.

Comment: hello @nvoigt but those are not futures right? The second one is inside then so it should be pretty safe no? Also what do you mean by ignore all warnings?

Comment: hello @GuillaumeRoux I'm using Inkwell, will try with an other one, thank you

Comment: Does your IDE not give you warnings for calling methods and ignoring their return values if they are of type `Future<>`? If it does not, you may want to make sure it does.

Comment: no warning @nvoigt (I'm using vs code), but my functions are not of type Future<>

Comment: Well, yes, that is part of the problem. Your functions call other functions that *do* return futures, but since your functions don't, calling your function means the caller get the signal they are done, while in reality, they are not.

Comment: @nvoigt but Navigator.popAndPushNamed and pushNamed are not future no? im a bit list, could you please advice me about how properly redifine the flow?

Comment: My suggestion would be to use the package https://pub.dev/packages/pedantic to let your compiler do the legwork and find that out for you. Again, that might not actually solve your problem, but finding and fixing things that trigger warnings and might not be correct would be a good first step. *Maybe* it solves your problems, maybe it just solves problems you will never knew you had because you fixed them before they popped up.

Comment: i will try, many thanks @nvoigt